# Binding events for ajax calls - how do you do it?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events, binding

I have a "what's the best method" type of question, as i believe my current way of working is somewhat ambiguous ..

Starting off with a simple page with a few menu buttons.. Each menu  has a single event bound to it, in order to populate the main area in the following manner..

```
$('#admin_panel_inner>a').bind('click', function()
{
   $.get(url, function(data)
   {
      $('#admin_panel_wrapper').html(data);
   });
});
```

So far so good, but now my question really starts here.. I could ajax in any number of html templates with the method above, each containing a table, an edit button or a create button for example..

The next step I see however would be to bind the above buttons/links brought in by the ajax to another set of event handlers to catch their click events.. I see this quickly getting out of control with many events bound that may not even exist..

If i require the layout manager page, how do i trigger the event listeners for JUST the layout and not for all of the other "could be" ajaxed html templates..

I hope that is a little clearer.. 
Thanks again,

Comment: Can you possibly add a better summary of what you'd like to do/what you're trying to avoid/what you want the end result to be?

I think I have some idea but I don't want to answer if I don't completely understand the question.

Comment: Updated, i hope that is a little clearer

Comment: at document ready bind events by live method instead of bind. it will bind elements that are generated later too.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, i understand the use of live, however in this method i would have loads of live bindings waiting for ajax pages that hadnt been used.. It seems really hard to maintain.

Comment: Will the callback function always remain the same? Appending the new data to the wrapper?

Comment: Only the first Ajax call, as that populates an area on the page.. Everything else will need unique callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best method is the least obtrusive.

Usually I make an `init()` function that is called when the DOM is ready. It hooks up all the event handlers based on ID and class name. I avoid inline "onclick" as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Diodeus, from what i understand you bind all the events even if the ajax request doesn't bring back the particular code for that event?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please explain when you want to do.

Comment: I have updated the summary with what i hope is a easy to understand summary.. Thanks again.